# What is the syntax for having both 'is' and 'using' in a contract declaration?

Tags: solidity

I have a contract which inherits from some other contract and uses some library.

I tried the following ways for declaring it, none of which works:

```
contract B is A  using Lib
contract B is A, using Lib
contract B is A; using Lib
contract B using Lib  is A
contract B using Lib, is A
contract B using Lib; is A
```

UPDATE:

I found this answer [here](https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/soliditys-using-keyword-c05c18aaa088):

```
contract B is A {
    using Lib for *;
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't quite achieve what I was hoping to, since I still need to prepend `Lib.` on every call to a function of `Lib`.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need to prepend `Lib.` if you've done `using Lib for *`. Can you show us the code for `Lib` and `B`?

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer so it can be marked as resolved. Thanks!